# Scrollview (findviewby id) returns null

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os, android-scrollview

There is an imageview within a scrollview with an extra long image which is currently scrollable.  I am trying to get this image to scroll by itself, however the findViewById keeps returning null on the scroll view.

EDIT:  This is on the android wear

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.mtr_scrollView);
    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)sv.findViewById(R.id.something)
    //sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());

    sv.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            //sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
        }
    });

    final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
    stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
            mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);

        }
    });

    handler = new Handler();

    nodeListener = new NodeApi.NodeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {
            remoteNodeId = node.getId();
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.SUCCESS_ANIMATION);
            intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, getString(R.string.peer_connected));
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            });
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ConfirmationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_ANIMATION_TYPE, ConfirmationActivity.FAILURE_ANIMATION);
            intent.putExtra(ConfirmationActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE, getString(R.string.peer_disconnected));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

    messageListener = new MessageApi.MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
            byte[]bytes = messageEvent.getData();
            final String temp = new String(bytes);
            if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(MESSAGE_PATH)) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

    };

    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext()).addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

            Wearable.NodeApi.addListener(apiClient, nodeListener);
            Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(apiClient, messageListener);

            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(apiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult getConnectedNodesResult) {
                    if (getConnectedNodesResult.getStatus().isSuccess() && getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes().size() > 0) {
                        remoteNodeId = getConnectedNodesResult.getNodes().get(0).getId();

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }
    }).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
}
```

I am attempting to scroll get the image inside the scrollview to scroll automatically once the app starts.

XML as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity" tools:deviceIds="wear_round"
android:background="@color/black">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mtr_scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/something">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/sample"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Initialize ScrollView same as WatchViewStub remove `MainActivity.this`

Comment: Changed that, still receive this error.  java.lang.             RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cherrypicks.mtr_demo/com.example.cherrypicks.mtr_demo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.ScrollView.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at xml you posted the problem is not the ScrollView but `WatchViewStub`. Get rid of

```
final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
        mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.text);

    }
});
```

**EDIT**

if you are using a `WatchViewStub`, the you have to wain `onLayoutInflated` to initialize your views, and you have to use the `stub` parameter:

```
final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub)       findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
        final ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)  stub.findViewById(R.id.mtr_scrollView);

        sv.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: Forgot to mention this is on the android wear.  So wouldn't i need the WatchViewStub in order for it to determine whether to use round or square layout?

Comment: are you using a WatchStub? If yes then you have to use `stub` to initialize every views

Comment: Thanks your code works! it just shows a black screen which I assume is because it scrolls down extremely quickly...any way to make it scroll slower?